# Google WebApp API call returns no JSON

Tags: jquery, json, google-apps-script, web-applications, cross-origin-read-blocking

I'm trying to execute a doGet function of a Google Spreadsheet in order to get some data from the sheet. The data has to be returned within a JSON object. For now, I am returning simple dummy content within the JSON object because I haven't been able yet to receive the JSON object and to read data from it.

I'm having a simple doGet function, which is called by an HTML site.

The doGet function contains a count() function which counts every call to this doGet function. That way I know, that doGet is executed (this part works fine).

```js
function doGet(e){
  //add +1 to value of a specific spreadsheet cell;
  //count() always works, even though I don't get the JSON object.
  count(); 
  
  var content = {
      "answer": "This is an answer",
      "body" : "Welcome to the web app."
  };
 
  //convert JavaScript object into a string 
  //so that it can be sent
  var JSONString = JSON.stringify(content);  
  
  var JSONOutput = ContentService.createTextOutput(JSONString);
  JSONOutput.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  return JSONOutput;  
}
```

Now, I created an HTML site that calls this doGet function. I'm logging some parts to see, what is actually executed.

```html
<html>
    
<head>        
<title>Call GAPI</title>        
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>    

<body>
<script src="./jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        
<script>
           
console.log("Prepare API Call"); 
            
$(function(){         
 $.getJSON('https://script.google.com/macros/s/*encrpyted-URL*/exec?callback=?', function(json) {                   
    var json = JSON.parse(result); //parsing is necessary because response is actually a TextOutput which needs to be turned into a javascript object          
    console.log(json.answer); //not executed             
 console.log("Done API Call"); //not executed         
  });            
});
            
console.log("End");   

</script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Most of the time I see this in the console:

```
Prepare API Call
End
```

So, everything besides the API call is executed. 
Sometimes, I get an CORB error blocking as well, which is weird because it doesn't always appear:

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://script.google.com/macros/s/myURL/exec?callback=jQuery331014863254459179753_1548439425031&_=1548439425032 with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

Isn't it weird that it says that I received a text/html response? In the doGet function the returned object is declared as a JSON object. Yet, goGet returns a TextOutput object or string. That's why it needs to be parsed...
I don't know why I can't read the returned JSON object and why I'm getting this CORB error. Can someone help me?

One more thing: Calling with URL/exec only is "blocked by CORS policy"; so I somehow need to add URL/exec?callback=? to solve this.

Comment: is the callback=? removed for security?  this is not a function, also you need a dataType to be jsonp - see: https://www.sitepoint.com/jsonp-examples/

Comment: Thanks for the Link! I didn't want to leave it because of security reasons; I just tried to use it without the attribute because that's the way like the Google webapp link presents it. So I keep trying it with URL/exec?callback=? but the result remains the same (CORB blocking and no console result of the JSON object)

Comment: CORS blocking is coming from the server. Do you have any control over the setup? I have had run ins many times with this, and you can whitelist some requests through the server headers. this will let the browser know everything is ok.  Laravel, for example has a package that handles much of it for you. But all of this is a moot point is you do not have any access to the server backend you are contacting. You can also install a chrome extension that overrides the cors checking, but generally I'd recommend against except for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the values from Web Apps as a JSONP response.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? I think that there might be several answers for your situation. So please think of this as just one of them.

### Modification points:

#### For Google Apps Script side

- Use `ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT` to `setMimeType`.
- Modify `createTextOutput` to `e.parameter.callback + '(' + JSONString + ')'`.

#### For HTML side

- `result` of `var json = JSON.parse(result)` is not declared. And `JSON.parse()` is not required.

### Modified script:

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Google Apps Script side

From:

```
var JSONOutput = ContentService.createTextOutput(JSONString);
JSONOutput.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
```

To:

```
var JSONOutput = ContentService.createTextOutput(e.parameter.callback + '(' + JSONString + ')');
JSONOutput.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
```

#### HTML side

From:

```
$.getJSON('https://script.google.com/macros/s/*encrpyted-URL*/exec?callback=?', function(json) {
var json = JSON.parse(result);
console.log(json.answer);
console.log("Done API Call");
```

To:

```
$.getJSON('https://script.google.com/macros/s/*encrpyted-URL*/exec?callback=?', function(json) {
console.log(json.answer);
console.log("Done API Call");
```

### Note:

- **When you modify the script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to Web Apps.**
- When you run Javascript of HTML, you will see the values of `Prepare API Call`, `End`, `This is an answer` and `Done API Call` in order because of the asynchronous processing.

### References:

- [ContentService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/content-service)
- [MimeType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/mime-type)

If this was not the result you wanted, I apologize.

Comment: It's awesome, it works! Thank you so much, you're my hero! I put lots of time into this, finally it works. I haven't understood yet, why I need to use the Mimetype JavaScript instead of JSON, but I'm going to have a look into your references tomorrow.

Comment: @Eleandro Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Because JSONP is Javascript that JSON object is wrapped by a callback function, ``ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT`` (``application/javascript``) is used as the mimeType. This might be useful for you. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP